# Show that:$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}{\gamma\over x}+e^{-\gamma/x}\prod\limits_{y=1}^{\infty}\left({xy\over 1+xy}\right){e^{1/(xy)}}=1$

Tags: limits, infinite-product, euler-mascheroni-constant

I always want to know if this limit hold or not.

Please show that

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left[{\gamma\over x}+e^{-{\gamma\over x}}\prod_{y=1}^{\infty}\left({xy\over 1+xy}\right){e^{{1\over xy}}}\right]=1\tag1$$

Where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant; $\gamma=0.577216...$

My try:

Re write

$$\left(1-{\gamma\over x}\right)e^{\gamma \over x}=\prod_{y=1}^{\infty}\left({xy\over 1+xy}\right){e^{1\over xy}}$$

Take the ln

$${\gamma\over x}+\ln{\left(1-{\gamma\over x}\right)}=\sum_{y=1}^{\infty}\ln{\left(xy\over 1+xy\right){e^{1\over xy}}}$$

$${\gamma\over x}+\ln{\left(1-{\gamma\over x}\right)}=\ln{\left({x\over 1+x}\right){e^{1\over x}}}+\ln{\left({2x\over 1+2x}\right){e^{1\over 2x}}}+
\ln{\left({3x\over 1+3x}\right){e^{1\over 3x}}}+\cdots$$

any hints what to do next? Or else prove $(1)$

Comment: Wow. Just... wow.

Comment: Have you encountered the product expansion of the Gamma function?

Comment: what evidence do we have that the limit holds?

Comment: The limit should be 0, not 1, I suspect...

Comment: @tired As written, the product diverges.

Comment: @Dr.MV thanks for the clarification (+1)

Comment: @tired Happy New Year my friend!

Comment: @Dr.MV a happy new year for you too, of course!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**THIS IS A RESPONSE TO THE ORIGINALLY POSTED QUESTION**

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\log\left(\left(\frac{xy}{1+xy}\right)^{e^{\frac1{xy}}}\right)&={e^{\frac1{xy}}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{1+xy}\right)}\\\\
&=\left(1+\frac1{xy}+O\left(\frac{1}{(xy)^2}\right)\right)\left(-\frac{1}{1+xy}+O\left(\frac{1}{(1+xy)^2}\right)\right)\\\\
&=-\frac1{xy}+O\left(\frac1{(xy)^2}\right)
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as $\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{y=1}^N \frac{-1}{xy}=-\infty$, the infinite product approaches $0$.

---

Note that if instead of the term $\left(\frac{xy}{1+xy}\right)^{e^{\frac{1}{xy}}}$ we had $\left(\frac{xy}{1+xy}\right)\,e^{\frac{1}{xy}}$, then the product represents

$$e^{-\gamma/x}\prod_{y=1}^\infty \left(\frac{xy}{1+xy}\right)\,e^{\frac{1}{xy}}=\frac1x \Gamma(1/x)\to 1\,\,\text{as}\,\,x\to \infty$$

Comment: And this also shows, that at least the sequence of the partial products converges to 0. Nice :)

Comment: You are right @Dr. MV I wrote it wrong. I will edit it. (+1) should be as you said $\left({xy\over 1+xy}\right)e^{1\over xy}$